# Parameters are not being POSTED in AFNetworking while using GET

Tags: php, objective-c

What I'm trying to do is a **LOGIN** scenario. I'm using **AFNetworking 3.0** and passing the username and password as parameters as shown in the code below:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"ePharmUserUsername":self.usernameTf.text,@"ePharmUserPassword":self.passwordTf.text};
 AFHTTPSessionManager *mgr = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
mgr.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[mgr.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[mgr.requestSerializer setValue:@"utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept-charset"];
[mgr GET:LOGIN parameters:parameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
}
success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"response is : %@",responseObject);

      if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] == 104) {
          UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"Internal Error"
                                        message:[responseObject objectForKey:@"message"]
                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

          UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                     {}];

          [alert addAction:okButton];
          [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
          [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

          /********************MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_PART*********************/
          okButton  = nil;
          alert= nil;
          /********************MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_PART*********************/

      }


    else if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] == 106) {
        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Missing Credantials"
                                      message:[responseObject objectForKey:@"message"]
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {}];

        [alert addAction:okButton];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        /********************MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_PART*********************/
        okButton  = nil;
        alert= nil;
        /********************MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_PART*********************/

    }
      else
      {


          [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

      }



  }
  failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      NSLog(@"the error is: %@",error);
      [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


  }];
```

Also I'm using **PHP** as backend with **MySQL** as database server.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8;');
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES UTF8");
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, "ePharm") or die("Cannot select Database.");

    $response = array();
    $response["Username"] = array();

    if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $Username = $_POST['ePharmUserUsername'];
    $Password = $_POST['ePharmUserPassword'];

    if (empty($Username) || empty($Password)) {
        $response["success"] = 106;
        $response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    else
  {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ePharmUser WHERE ePharmUserUsername='$Username' AND ePharmUserPassword = '$Password'";        
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if (empty($row)) {
        $response["success"] = 108;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Username or Password";
        die(json_encode($response));
        }

        if (!empty($row)) {
        $users = array();   
        $users["ePharmUserId"] = $row["ePharmUserId"];
        $users["ePharmUserName"] = $row["ePharmUserName"];
        $users["ePharmUserPhoneNumber"] = $row["ePharmUserPhoneNumber"];
        $users["ePharmUserProfilePictureUrl"] = $row["ePharmUserProfilePictureUrl"];
        $users["ePharmUserPassword"] = $row["ePharmUserPassword"];
        $users["ePharmUserEmail"] = $row["ePharmUserEmail"];
        $users["ePharmUserUsername"] = $row["ePharmUserUsername"];
        array_push($response["Username"], $users);
        $response["success"] = 100;
        $response["message"] = "success";
        die(json_encode($response));   

     }

} 

    }


      else {
        $response["success"] = 104;
        $response["message"] = "The App was unable to Post Data to DB Error 
        104";
          die(json_encode($response));
        }
```

When I'm posting data from the objective-c code (client side) the process reaches the `(!empty($_POST))` in **PHP** that is always false and so goes to the else statement. I already searched for some solutions. Here is what I found [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594584/after-setting-custom-headers-in-afnetworking-2-x-the-parameters-are-not-being-r) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594584/after-setting-custom-headers-in-afnetworking-2-x-the-parameters-are-not-being-r) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931861/how-to-post-parameter-like-register-id3-in-afnetworking), but they don't fit in my situation. Any help?

Comment: Well, that would be because when you do a `GET`, the parameters are in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: Honestly, that's not worthy of an answer.  I'd prefer this be closed.